# ZIP compressed input for Apache Flink

Tags: zip, apache-flink

I need to read and processes **a specific file within a zip archive** in Apache Flink.

In the documentation, I found that

> Flink currently supports transparent decompression of input files if these are marked with an appropriate file extension.

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/batch/#read-compressed-files

Is it possible process it while decompressing on the fly in Apache Flink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to share the solution I implemented meanwhile.

So, after created my own `InputFormat` I used the following code within the `open()` method:

```
@Override
public void open(final FileInputSplit ignored) throws IOException {
    ...
    final XMLInputFactory xmlif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    final XMLStreamReader xmlr = xmlif.createXMLStreamReader(filePath.toString(),
              InputFormatUtil.readFileWithinZipArchive(filePath, nestedXmlFileName));
    while (xmlr.hasNext()) {
    ...
}
```

where the implementation of `readFileWithinZipArchive(...)` is:

```
public static InputStream readFileWithinZipArchive(final Path zipPath, final String filename) throws IOException {
    // using org.apache.flink.core.fs.Path for getting the InputStream from the (remote) zip archive
    final InputStream zipInputStream = zipPath.getFileSystem().open(zipPath);
    // generating a temporary local copy of the zip file
    final File tmpFile = stream2file(zipInputStream);
    // then using java.util.zip.ZipFile for extracting the InputStream for the specific file within the zip archive
    final ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(tmpFile);
    return zipFile.getInputStream(zipFile.getEntry(filename));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `FileInputFormat` will delegate the reading compressed files to `GZIPInputStream`, which will return partial decompressed data while decompressing.

Comment: Hi @David what do you mean for _partial decompressed data while decompressing_? Could you provide some example that explains it better?

Comment: For example, assuming we have a large zipped file having a size of 10G. While processing, instead of waiting several seconds or minutes to wait for the decompressing, `GZIPInputStream` returns the uncompressed data immediately once we open the file.

Comment: So, given that I have a compressed folder, not a file, and I would process the data from a specific file contained in that compressed folder, using for instance `java.util.zip.ZipFile` for reading a zipEntry, which data I should expect from the `GZIPInputStream`?

Comment: `GZIPInputStream` actually is wrapped in the Flink's API, like `readTextFile`. When the file is ending with `gz`, for example, the API decompress the data automatically. But you cannot specify some file in the compressed to process. Another way is to implement your own `InputFormat`, then you could use `ZipFile` to choose the desired `ZipEntry` to read content from specific files in the zip file.

Comment: Thanks David, this is what I did. I think there isn't any other way.

Comment: No worries. Glad to help ;)