# Flink `textInputFormat` does not process GZ compressed files from aws S3 `Source` file system

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I followed ([ZIP compressed input for Apache Flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49122170/zip-compressed-input-for-apache-flink?newreg=4dce460b71504a16ab651b171da287de)) and wrote the following code piece to process `.gz` log files in a dir with a simple `TextInputFormat`. It works on my local test directory, scans and automatically opens the `.gz` file contents. However, when I run it with an s3 bucket source, it does not process `.gz` compressed files. This Flink job still opens `.log` files on the s3 bucket though. Seems it just does not uncompress the `.gz` files. How can I get this resolved on s3 file system?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    final ParameterTool params = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);
    final String sourceLogDirPath = params.get("source_log_dir_path", "s3://my-test-bucket-logs/"); // "/Users/my.user/logtest/logs"
    final Long checkpointInterval = Long.parseLong(params.get("checkpoint_interval", "60000"));
    
    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
    env.enableCheckpointing(checkpointInterval, CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE);
    env.getCheckpointConfig().enableExternalizedCheckpoints(
        CheckpointConfig.ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION);
    env.getConfig().setGlobalJobParameters(params);

    TextInputFormat textInputFormat = new TextInputFormat(new Path(sourceLogDirPath));
    textInputFormat.setNestedFileEnumeration(true);

    DataStream<String> stream = env.readFile(
            textInputFormat, sourceLogDirPath,
            FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY, 100);

    stream.print();
    env.execute();
}
```

This is my classpath jar flink libs:

/opt/flink/lib/flink-csv-1.13.2.jar:/opt/flink/lib/flink-json-1.13.2.jar:/opt/flink/lib/flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:/opt/flink/lib/flink-table-blink_2.12-1.13.2.jar:/opt/flink/lib/flink-table_2.12-1.13.2.jar:/opt/flink/lib/log4j-1.2-api-2.12.1.jar:/opt/flink/lib/log4j-api-2.12.1.jar:/opt/flink/lib/log4j-core-2.12.1.jar:/opt/flink/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.12.1.jar:/opt/flink/lib/sentry_log4j2_deploy.jar:/opt/flink/lib/flink-dist_2.12-1.13.2.jar:::

P.S. I also tried `s3a://<bucket>/` with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can change the log to debug mode and observe whether the file is filtered out when the file is split.

By default, files beginning with ‘.’ or ‘_‘ will be filtered out

[image]

Comment: This answer was really helpful. After looking into debug logs, I noticed the file path had `//` in it (basically an empty dir / with no name ) and hence Flink was not able to open and scan inside that dir. This double slash file path is a common issue with `vector` (service from datadog to pipe logs) configuration when it sets an s3 sink.

Comment: @AF will this code work from local to read s3 file contents? I tried but it didn't work. Is there any codes I have to add for credentials?

Comment: @codeSeeker the sourceLogDirPath in the code refers to `s3://`. I remember I tested that with a local drive path and it was working just fine.

Comment: @AF I meant I'm running code in my system, but source path I'm trying to read is in s3 bucket, is it working for you?